# Symfony2 : displaying form entity field type as radio buttons

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to display all categories (from my table Category) with radio buttons.
There are 3 categories but only one radio button is displayed while the Doctrine query is OK.

My FormType code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'title',
        'property_path' => false,
    ));
}
```

My Twig code :

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

The result should return 3 radio buttons, but I see only one radio button (the first in my table).

The Doctrine query displayed in the Symfony profiler (debug bar) is executed perfectly and returns 3 rows.

Maybe the problem comes from the "property_path" that I had to add, otherwise I had an exception :

```
Neither property "categories" nor method "getCategories()" nor method "isCategories()" exists in class ...
```

Any help please ?

Many thanks :-)

Aurel

EDIT :

Here is my dev.log corresponding to this request, when removing the "property_path" :

```
[2012-04-26 07:27:01] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.last_update AS last_update2, t0.title AS title4 FROM category t0 ([]) [] []
[2012-04-26 07:27:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2012-04-26 07:27:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2012-04-26 07:27:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2012-04-26 07:27:01] request.CRITICAL: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidPropertyException: Neither property "categories" nor method "getCategories()" nor method "isCategories()" exists in class "Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Category" (uncaught exception) at /www/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php line 316 [] []
```

I really don't understand why it refused to display each row of my Category table...

Comment: 'property_path' option only affect the binding of the form.
Have you read the logs? There is maybe an error.

Comment: See my edit for the dev.log corresponding...

Comment: Any more help ? How could I display my 3 radio buttons ? Why aren't they all retrieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my Entity was not properly set.  The `$id` field was a boolean instead of being an integer.